# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openalpr_api

Tags: pycharm, openalpr

I am working on the following project in `github`.
https://github.com/ShreyAmbesh/Traffic-Rule-Violation-Detection-System

installed all the needed packages for the project but when i try to run the project in pycharm i am getting the following error...

```
File "VehicleMoniter.py", line 21, in 
import openalpr_api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openalpr_api'
```

I also installed openalpr in my system

```
C:\Users\preetha\Desktop\python project\traffic project\Traffic-Rule-Violation-Detection-System-master>pip install openalpr
Requirement already satisfied: openalpr in c:\users\preetha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (1.0.12)
```

I don't know how to solve this error.

Anyone please help me...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect your system with (OpenALPR cloud) for running this project. To do that you need to have access into an active OpenALPR account. If you haven't one then create for free in here:
https://cloud.openalpr.com/account/register

To install the agent or openalpr-api or openalpr cloud run the following command:

bash <(curl -s https://deb.openalpr.com/install)

Then the system will ask for your openalpr credentials

Then choose your installation as required by the project.....

For further details look at url:
http://doc.openalpr.com/on_premises.html

Answer (score 0):

I had to ***also*** install python bindings before python could talk to OpenALPR.
In Ubuntu 19.10 this is very easy (note, alpr is broken in some versions of Ubuntu, e.g. 18.04):

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-openalpr
sudo apt-get install -y python3-openalpr
```

To get the rest of OpenALPR (Ubuntu 19.10):

```
apt-get update
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 
apt-get install -y openalpr
cd /usr/share/openalpr/runtime_data/ocr/
cp tessdata/lus.traineddata .
```

(The last 2 lines fix a bug in 19.10)